# How to check lon/lat polygon pixels over land or ocean quickly?

Tags: python, numpy, shapely, cartopy

I have 2d lon/lat arrays and am trying to check the land type like this:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from shapely.ops import unary_union

lon = np.arange(-180, 181, .1)
lat = np.arange(-90, 91, .1) 
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

land_shp_fname = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m',  
                                         category='physical', name='land')

land_geom = unary_union(list(shpreader.Reader(land_shp_fname).geometries()))

grid_names = np.empty_like(lons, dtype=int)

for i in range(len(lon)-1):
    for j in range(len(lat)-1):
        poly = Polygon([(lon[i], lat[j]), (lon[i+1], lat[j]),  
                        (lon[i+1], lat[j+1]), (lon[i], lat[j+1])])
        if poly.intersects(land_geom):
            grid_names[j,i] = 1 # Land
        else:
            grid_names[j,i] = 0 # Ocean
```

The speed is slow for creating the high-resolution one for 1000x1000 pixels. Any suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the [roaring_landmask](https://github.com/gauteh/roaring-landmask) package is really fast:

```
import numpy as np
from roaring_landmask import RoaringLandmask

lon = np.arange(-180, 180, .1)
lat = np.arange(-90, 90, .1) 
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

l = RoaringLandmask.new()
mask = l.contains_many(lons.ravel(), lats.ravel())
```

It costs around 5s on my laptop ;)

### Update

I find it's better to use geopandas and cartopy do this, because `roaring_landmask` doesn't consider lake as not_land type.

Here's an example of checking points. It should be similar for polygons.

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoSeries
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

def random_lon_lat(n=1, lat_min=-90., lat_max=90., lon_min=-180., lon_max=180.):
    """
    this code produces an array with pairs lat, lon
    """
    lat = np.random.uniform(lat_min, lat_max, n)
    lon = np.random.uniform(lon_min, lon_max, n)

    points = GeoSeries(gpd.points_from_xy(lon, lat))
    points_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points, crs="EPSG:4326")

    return points_gdf

points_gdf = random_lon_lat(int(1e6))

land_50m = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical','land','50m')
land_polygons_cartopy = list(land_50m.geometries())

land_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(crs='epsg:4326', geometry=land_polygons_cartopy)

# Spatially join the points with the land polygons
joined = gpd.sjoin(points_gdf, land_gdf, how='left', op='within')

# Check if each point is within a land polygon
is_within_land = joined['index_right'].notnull()
```

It takes less than 1 second to check all point types.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just rasterize the `land_geom`, since, that is what your code is doing.

Starting from your code (replacing `grid_names=` and the double for loop)

```py
grid_names=rasterio.features.rasterize([land_geom], out_shape=(1000,1000), transform=rasterio.features.Affine(360/1000,0,-180,0,-180/1000,90))
```

Takes 0.02 seconds on my machine (that is roughly what you are doing, but with all iterations done internally)

Note the transformation matrix, that converts coordinate from the output grid into coordinates in the input shape. It is matrix, where a,b,c,d,e,f are the 6 parameters

```
⎡a  b  c⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢d  e  f⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣0  0  1⎦
```

So point at pixel x=800, y=700 of the output array is lon = 360/1000×800+0×700-180×1 = 108, lat = 0×800 - 180/1000×700+90 = -36

The negative sign for `y` transform is to have the higher latitudes at the top of the image, assuming that image is (as it is traditionnaly) plotted with y=0 at the top.

So, with matplotlib

```
plt.imshow(grid_names)
```

shows
[image]

Comment: Interesting method. I suppose this is only applicable to regular grids? If we have unequal 2D lons/lats, this won't work. Anyway, this solution is really useful!

Comment: Indeed, afaik, this is only for regular grid. There are many way to create a transform, including some specified from matching points. But afaik, they all end up into an affine transform. What I would do, to have unregular transform, is to transform input rather than rasterization. For example, you can create a Peters projection with `def peters(xy): xy[:,1]=90*np.sin(xy[:,1]*np.pi/180); return xy` `transform(land_geom, peters)`.